# Ocaml - regexp matching words separated by comma doesn't work

Tags: regex, ocaml

I try to know is a string is well formed as a string separated by comma like "foo,bar,bang" and a string like "foo," should be not matched.

I don't understand why my regexp doesn't work on the following example :

```
#load "str.cma"

let regexp = Str.regexp "[a-ZA-Z0-9]+(,[a-ZA-Z0-9]+)*"
let str = "foo,bar,bang"  
let s = Str.string_match regexp str 0
```

My regex seems good but the returning result by the last line is false. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: What about `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`? I think the problem is that there are problems with the ranges in [].

Comment: It's true that I gave a bad range with [a-Z] but with the regexp in your post, it doesn't work too.

Comment: Does this `if Str.string_match (Str.regexp "[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*") "foo,bar,bang" 0 
then print_string "ok";;` print 'ok'? Before, also add ";;" after `#load "str.cma"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses `( ... )` match actual parentheses in OCaml regular expressions. To get grouping parentheses you need to use `\( ... \)`.

So, the following should work:

```
#load "str.cma";;

let regexp = Str.regexp "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)*"
let str = "foo,bar,bang"  
let s = Str.string_match regexp str 0;;
```

Notes:

- Need to escape `\` in a string constant, hence `\\( ... \\)`
- I fixed your `a-z` ranges

Comment: With OCaml 4.02 you can avoid escaping the \ by using the alternative string syntax: `{|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)*|}`.